# Can't connect to my SSH on RPi3 after it going to sleep mode for inactivity

Tags: ssh, putty, raspberry-pi, raspbian

When I bought my raspberry pi3 I went home and setup the SSH and the static IP as 192.168.8.8 on it. I connected to it using putty and it worked well until it went to sleep mode after sometime of inactivity and after that I have yet to connect to it again, I re-flashed Rasbian ***twice*** on it and it worked again but yet again after going to sleep mode I can't connect to it anymore, when connecting to it all I get is:

> Network error: Connection timed out

The outputs of `ip link`, `ip route` and `ip address`:

#### `ip link`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enxb827ebdec400: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:de:c4:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:8b:91:55 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

#### `ip route`:

```
<empty, nothing at all>
```

#### `ip address`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enxb827ebdec400: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:de:c4:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:8b:91:55 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: You either have to make it no go in sleep mode, or make it wake up when you try to access it by the LAN (this is usually called "Wake-On-LAN").

Comment: @xenoid I am unable to connect it after it goes to sleep even if i do wake it up or reboot it.

Comment: One possibility is that the IP setuo when it wakes up/reboots isn't the one you think (for whatever reason). Can you connect to the RPi with real keyboard/display (not through SSH)? What says `ifcong` in that case (interface address and status). Otherwise did you try to check if there are new devices showing up on the LAN when it wakes up/reboots? Or, attacking the problem from the other side, what happens if you make it use a  DHCP-assigned address?

Comment: @xenoid Yes i can, I plugged the keyboard and HDMI in it and did `ifconfig` and it was the IP i assigned it (192.168.8.8), even when I logged in to the router and checked the devices connected and the IP was coorrect, then I tried connecting to the ssh using the RPi and connected succesfully

Comment: So, it works now?

Comment: No, i can connect to it on the pi itself but nowhere else on the same network. @xenoid

Comment: Please add to your initial question the outputs of `ip link`, `ip route` and `ip address` when things works and when they don't.

Comment: @xenoid Mind explaining `ip link` and `ip route`, I don't understand what you mean with these..

Comment: Just run these commands and add their output here (part of iproute2 package, but likely already installed). Their output just show about everything there is to know about your network connections.

Comment: @xenoid I added the info to the main question as asked but only when things don't work since I am not able to connect to it, hence I can't do it when it works

Comment: `NO-CARRIER` is the problem, to get this on my PC I have to physically unplug the Ethernet, if I just disable the link I don't see it. So it starts to look like a problem with the hardware interface. Is the thing still under warranty?